# Integrating Google search to an Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, google-search

Even a Snippet of an android code to Integrate Google Search into an Edit text will be really useful, according to my requirement i don't want the google search data or whatever but only the dropdown so that it will b easier for people to type and don't have to waste time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see about the componenent is [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

An editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

Comment: thanks for your kind response but unfortunately my requirement is that I want Google Search into an Edit Text to Auto Complete even the words that is not yet with us. As for your information it is for a Movie Storing App where the user will be able to store movie name, and the movie name should be auto completed while the user is typing :), If you can Please give me a ideal solution thanks in advance :)

Comment: how can you display auto complete texts when you doesn't have data with you. Even you can do like this..Simply enter text and by using `setoneditoractionlistener` and when text length reaches 4 chars then you can call web for results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, but brother still you didn't get my requirement, it is because we dont know what is the movie name he wants to save in the database. We want to use google search and then make the user convenient and comfortable in typing the things. And please remember I'm not asking for something like google search my requirement itself is google search hope u understood now. Thanks in Advance :)